# Nuget pack on a web project renames all content files to 'content'

Tags: nuget

When running 'nuget pack' on a web project, I get a lot of errors saying that a file named 'content' is already added into the package.

For example:

> WARNING: File 'SlowCheetah.Transforms.targets' is not added because the package already contains file 'content'
>   WARNING: File 'Web.config' is not added because the package already contains file 'content'

Looking into the generated package, I find out that the 'content' file is actually one of the content files (the first one it finds), so the what the warnings are telling me is that every content file in the project is being packaged as 'content'.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Having this problem right now. :( Is making it difficult to cleanly deploy in Octopus Deploy with a nuget package rather than just copying files.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this one?

Comment: Hi @MarcinZajkowski! Please see my answer below.

Comment: Thanks. I also experienced a lot of problems building it from .csproj. Switching right now to using nuspec file.

Comment: Good. Let me know if you have any other concern. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the end what I did was creating the file structure for the nuget package and packaging from there rather than from the project itself. I actually got more control for what's included rather than giving the VS folder the full responsibility for that.

Using this as a reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/nuget/create-packages/creating-a-package
I recommend creating the tools, lib, content and build folder structure and publish into it from the web project. You can adjust the nuspec file with your dependencies.

Almost 2 years using this approach :)